# android Java how can I add new textline from TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, settext

I have a TextView. and firstly I set a line via for loop. array[0], array [1]...
at the first time textView has "work", and then I want to add "is", "a" like these strings.
However, each time old line deleted and set new line!!!

```
             inputs2 = inputs.getText().toString();
             String[] words = inputs2.split(",");

             int n= words.length;
             for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                 resultView.setText(words[i]);

             }
```

How can I add new textline without deleted old one.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you put some code snippets showing what you have achieved so far? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append String values to a TextView, you can use the `append()` method:

```
String [] array;
TextView textView;

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    textView.append(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: @user2575834 If it's the right answer, tick the check mark to validate the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can your \n\r with append method for new line

```
resultView.append(words[i]+"\n\r");
```

Comment: `\n\r` on an Android device? Really? ^^

Comment: Even though it works O_o, you should prefer to use this: `String lineSep = System.getProperty("line.separator");`